# Trigger events with JQuery on  a CSS3 :after pseudo-element?

Tags: jquery, css, event-handling

I have this CSS

```
#popup .title:hover:after {
    content: "hide";
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: -32px;
    background: orange;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

and wanted to use a click event on it to `.remove()` the  `<div id="#popup">` But:

```
$('#popup .title:hover:after').length
```

returns 0 on document ready..

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: well i guess i can create dinamically the element with javascript... but just curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way?

Sorry, no. Pseudo-elements created with `:after` (or `:before`, or the CSS 3 equivalents `::after` and `::before`) are not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be selected.

From the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html):

> Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it
>   is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for
>   reparsing).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Pseduo elements aren't in the dom. So your browser won't be able to see them :(

As you want them to load in after the page has loaded or would have read the css i would do it with javascript using the after:

```
 $('#popup .title').after(); (you'll need to ploop your code in still)
```

and now that has been added i can play with it with javascript and remove etc etc.